# Dart Flutter image code redirects to image_provider

Tags: flutter, dart

**Code:**

```
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';

void main() {runApp(ModaApp());}

class ModaApp extends StatelessWidget {

  const ModaApp({Key? key}) : super(key: key);

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return MaterialApp(
      debugShowCheckedModeBanner: false,
      home: AnaSayfa(),
    );
  }
}

class AnaSayfa extends StatefulWidget {
  AnaSayfa({Key? key}) : super(key: key);

  @override
  State<AnaSayfa> createState() => _AnaSayfaState();
}

class _AnaSayfaState extends State<AnaSayfa> {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      appBar: AppBar(
        backgroundColor: Colors.transparent,
        elevation: 0,
        title: Text("Moda Uygulaması", style: TextStyle(fontFamily: "Montserrat", fontSize: 24, fontWeight: FontWeight.bold, color: Colors.black),),
        actions: [
          IconButton(icon: Icon(Icons.camera_alt), onPressed: () {}, color: Colors.grey,)
        ],
      ),
      body: ListView(
        children: [
          Container(
            color: Colors.blue,
            height: 150,
            width: double.infinity,
            child: ListView(
              scrollDirection: Axis.horizontal,
              children: <Widget>[
                listeElemani("assets/model1.jpeg", "assets/chanellogo.jpeg")
              ],
            ),
          ),
        ],
      ),
    );
  }

  Widget listeElemani(String imagePath, String logoPath) {

    return Column(
      children: <Widget>[
        Stack(
          children: <Widget>[
            Container(
              height: 75,
              width: 75,
              decoration: BoxDecoration(
                borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(40),
                image: DecorationImage(
                      image: AssetImage(logoPath), fit: BoxFit.contain),
                ),

              
            )
          ],
        )
      ],
    );
  }
}
```

When I try to run the code it redirects me to a file named `image_provider.dart`.

There is a code like this in this file:

```
  @override
  ImageStreamCompleter load(AssetBundleImageKey key, DecoderCallback decode) {
    InformationCollector? collector;
    assert(() {
      collector = () sync* {
        yield DiagnosticsProperty<ImageProvider>('Image provider', this);
        yield DiagnosticsProperty<AssetBundleImageKey>('Image key', key);
      };
      return true;
    }());
    return MultiFrameImageStreamCompleter(
      codec: _loadAsync(key, decode),
      scale: key.scale,
      debugLabel: key.name,
      informationCollector: collector,
    );
  }
```

What is the problem? How can I solve it?

---

**Current view:**

[image]

**Appear in my tutorial:**

[image]

**File directory of the project:**

[image]

My goal is to make a fashion app. But here I am stuck. While my instructor doesn't get errors, I do.

Comment: Did you add your assets folder to your pubspec.yaml?

Comment: I didn't add it because my instructor didn't add it.

Comment: I don't know how your instructor set up the project, but flutter can't load any assets that aren't declared in pubspec.yaml